# Error en Chrome al descargar Excel creado por ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

Tengo el siguiente código en la vista:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("GeneraReporte", "Libro"))
{ %>
    <input id="format" runat="server" name="format" type="hidden" value="xls" />
    <input type="image" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Images/iconos/export_excel.png")%>" alt="Exportar Excel" />
<% } %>
```

En el Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GeneraReporte()
{          
    try
    {
        String format = Request.Form["format"];
        Reportes reportes = new Reportes();
        DataTable lista_tabla = new DataTable();
        String sql = "SELECT dato1, dato2 from empresa";
        conexion.conectar();
        MySqlDataAdapter datos = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion.con);
        conexion.cerrar();
        datos.Fill(lista_tabla);

        string nombre_display = "Listado";
        string nombreDataSource = "DataSet_Excel";
        string formatoNameRender = "Excel";
        string nameArchivoExcel = "Libro_Diario";
        string nombreReporte = "Report_libro.rdlc";

        reportes.solicitaReporte(format, nombre_display, lista_tabla, nombreDataSource, formatoNameRender, nameArchivoExcel, nombreReporte);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
    }

    return View();
}
```

En una clase de nombre Reportes, tengo las funciones que se encargan de generar el Excel:

```
public void solicitaReporte(string format, string nombre_display, dynamic query, string nombreDataSource, string formatoNameRender, string nameArchivoExcel, string nombreReporte)
{
    LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
    report.DisplayName = nombre_display;
    report.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/" + nombreReporte);
    ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
    reportDataSource.Value = query;
    reportDataSource.Name = nombreDataSource;
    report.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

    byte[] bytes = report.Render(formatoNameRender);
    this.downloadReport(bytes, format, nameArchivoExcel);

    //return System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(bytes, format);
}

private void downloadReport(byte[] data, string format, string nameArchivoExcel)
{
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);

    byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
    int length;
    long data_length;
    try
    {
        data_length = stream.Length;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nameArchivoExcel + "." + format);

        while (data_length > 0)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                buffer = new Byte[10000];
                data_length = data_length - length;
            }
            else
            {
                data_length = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null) { stream.Close(); }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
    }
}
```

Pero cuando intento descargar en Google Chrome, me dice

> Error: Error de red.

Descargo cualquier otro archivo de Internet y no tengo problemas.
Lo raro es que me funciona en el Firefox.

Me gustaría saber, que debería hacer para evitar ese problema.

¿Cómo lo hago para que me funcione en Google Chrome?

Quizás habrá que habilitar algo en la `web.config`. Me gustaría poder al menos reproducir el error.

Imagen de transporte de red en Mozilla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Google Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cual era el siguiente error?

Comment: Lo que te está diciendo en el ultimo error es que edites tu web.config si queres ver el stacktrace y mas info  sobre la excepción, no es recomendable si el servidor es de producción.

Comment: La sintaxis Razor inicia con @ la que usas <% %> es el motor ASPx.

Comment: weform uso, similar a razor....el error que muestra de la weboconfig, es cuando está en producción

Comment: Si @fredyfx , pero eso no tiene relevancia. Además, estoy trabajando en webform, similar a razor, lo unico que cambia es @ por <% %> o <%:%>.

El asunto está que no me deja descargar excel desde la google chrome. Pero cualquier otro archivo de internet puedo.

Quizas debo habiliar algo en la webconfig, algun permiso.

Comment: la relevancia que veo es por el tema de etiquetas mi estimado. Por otro lado, te recomiendo agregar la información de lo que se envía y recibe de ambos navegadores, utilizando la tecla F12, ve a redes y selecciona la petición que se hace para la exportación y compara de ambos navegadores, me refiero a esto: http://imgur.com/a/DZkT3

Comment: ok @fredyfx, publique la foto, para ver que sucede. gracias

Comment: @Danilo la 2da imagen le pertenece al mismo request? Podrías agregar las versiones de los navegadores que andas usando? Has intentado darle click derecho al enlace donde generas el reporte mediante: "guardar enlace como"

Comment: @fredyfx Agregue mas fotos detallando mas lo que muestra en google chrome y en el mozilla. La version del google chrome es: 53.0.2785.116
la del Mozilla es:48.0.2. Al darle click derecho, no genera guardar enlace, porque es un input con imagen de boton, que está dentro de un form, donde se comunica con el controller. Pero yo creo que el problema está en el codigo downloadReport, que me imagino que habria que inidcar algun parametro mas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, supuse que en la función downloadReport tenía algun problema, por lo tanto cambie la forma de hacerlo. Asi lo hice:

```
 public FileResult GeneraReporte(string format)//el format es "EXCEL"
    {
        string nombreDataSource="DataSet_1";

        string nombreReporte = "Report.rdlc";

        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        report.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/" + nombreReporte);

        report.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Value = query();
        reportDataSource.Name = nombreDataSource;            
        report.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

        report.Refresh();

        return GetFileContentResult(report, format, null, "TestReport");


    public FileContentResult GetFileContentResult(Report report, String format, String deviceInfo, String fileDownloadName)
    {
        String mimeType;
        String encoding;
        String filenameExtension;
        String[] streamIds;
        Warning[] warnings;

        FileContentResult fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(report.Render(format, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings), mimeType);
        fileContentResult.FileDownloadName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileDownloadName, filenameExtension);

        return fileContentResult;
    }
```

Lo único que me quedaría con duda, que sucede cuando es para pdf, el format debería ser igual a PDF??

Comment: Que bueno que encontraste la solución, por favor acepta tu propia respuesta. Saludos.